# after-effects jsx RenderQueue progress

Tags: jsx, after-effects

I've been searching for documentation on AfterEffect's RenderQueue for a few days now. I need to calculate the completed percentage of the queue.

In reviewing the cs3 scripting guide (the last released documentation that I know of), I've found that I can determine the number of items in the queue, and I can use the status of individual items to see if they're completed. This works, but I really want to display more granular progress, since the progress wont update until an entire render completes. Which means I see 0% for a few minutes, then 33.3%, then 66.6%, then 100%...

I was expecting to find a field or two on the RenderQueueItem that would tell me what's left to render, but there doesn't appear to be anything documented.

Has anyone tried this, am I up a creek, or just missing something?

Many Thanks!

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that After Effects will not allow you to run scripts concurrent to rendering, so you can't interactively work in parallel to the render process.

What you can do, depending on your needs, is to set the item in the render queue to write its progress to a log file:

```js
app.project.renderQueue.item(1).logType = LogType.ERRORS_AND_PER_FRAME_INFO;
```

Assuming your project name is "project.aep", a directory called "project.aep Logs" will be created in the project's directory. Inside you will find a rolling log file.

You could analyze this log externally to After Effects to understand what is the progress.